# Why is my table is not displaying when I write it 'onload'?

Tags: javascript, html

Something really weird is happening, it works when I `document.write()` outside the `window.onload = function(){}` But It doesn't when I call it from inside. Please note, the table is created (I can tell because I see the source).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>title</title>
<style type="text/css">
#chessboard{margin:0;padding:0;border:2px solid #000}
#chessboard td{margin:0;padding:0;height:44px;width:42px;border:1px solid #000;background-repeat:no-repeat}
#chessboard td.ws{background-color:#ddd}
#chessboard td.bs{background-color:#999}
#chessboard td.bp{background-image:url('./pieces/bp.png')}
#chessboard td.br{background-image:url('./pieces/br.png')}
#chessboard td.bn{background-image:url('./pieces/bn.png')}
#chessboard td.bb{background-image:url('./pieces/bb.png')}
#chessboard td.bq{background-image:url('./pieces/bq.png')}
#chessboard td.bk{background-image:url('./pieces/bk.png')}
#chessboard td.wp{background-image:url('./pieces/wp.png')}
#chessboard td.wr{background-image:url('./pieces/wr.png')}
#chessboard td.wn{background-image:url('./pieces/wn.png')}
#chessboard td.wb{background-image:url('./pieces/wb.png')}
#chessboard td.wq{background-image:url('./pieces/wq.png')}
#chessboard td.wk{background-image:url('./pieces/wk.png')}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map="",i,ii,wsbs=true;
var abc=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"];

map+="<div align=\"center\"><table id=\"chessboard\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody>";
for(i=8;i>0;i--){
map+="<tr>";
for(ii=0;ii<8;ii++){
map+="<td id=\""+abc[ii]+""+i+"\" class=\"";
if(wsbs==true)map+="ws";else map+="bs";
map+="\">&nbsp;</td>";
if(ii!=7)wsbs=!wsbs;
}
map+="</tr>";
}
map+="</tbody></table></div>";

//document.write(map); works here

window.onload = function(){
document.write(map);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `document.write()` after the page has loaded (via `window.onload()`), you effectively obliterate the page as it has already rendered. Instead you should set the `innerHTML` of some existing element on the page to the contents of `map`.  Since you have an empty `<body>`, it will be safe to write to the body's `innerHTML`.  Otherwise, I would recommend creating a placeholder `<div>` inside the `<body>` and modifying its `innerHTML` instead.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.body.innerHTML = map;
}
```

Comment: why you enclosed 'map' inside parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You're writting the table in your `<head>`, so your browser won't interpret it. You need to have this in body :

```
<script>
document.write(map);
</script>
```